# Python Selenium_find_elements : list index out of range Error

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to get some review from play store. However, when I roll down the page, I need to press the button 'more review' to get more.
I used find_elements_by_class_name and click(), but it popped up with list index out of range Error.Thus, I have tried to print out and it shows '[]'.
I have no idea to solve it.

```
# open all reviews 
# urls = ["https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
          id=com.fourdesire.fortunecity"]    

url = url+'&showAllReviews=true'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)  # wait dom ready 
for i in range(1, 10):
    # scroll to load other reviews
    print(i)
    driver.execute_script(
        'window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);') 
    time.sleep(1)
page = driver.page_source  
soup_expatistan = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
element2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("RveJvd snByac")[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
class FindByXpathCss():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.maximize_window()
        baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true"
        driver.get(baseUrl)

        scrolls = 3
        while True:
            scrolls -= 1
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
            time.sleep(3)
            if scrolls < 0:
                break

        buttonClick = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'')][contains(text(),'Full Review')]")))
        for element in buttonClick:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

        reviewText = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='UD7Dzf']")))


        for textreview in reviewText:
            print textreview.text

        reviewText = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='UD7Dzf']")))


        for textreview in reviewText:
            print textreview.text
```

first example

[image]

Second example

[image]

Comment: Which url are you hitting

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your code succeed. However, when I change another URL, it pop up with " selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ".I tried the another but it showed the same situation.The only thing I change is the location of driver.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fourdesire.fortunecity&showAllReviews=true

Comment: Also this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fourdesire.spacewalk

Comment: I have checked your url :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fourdesire.fortunecity&showAllReviews=true its working fine

Comment: This is also workking fine for me :: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fourdesire.spacewalk

Comment: Quite strange. I recheck again.The only thing I find is ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238). It shows up both URL, but yours is working.

Comment: Check attached screenshots and Just change your url and give a try from  your end you will get full reviews with both the links which you have mentioned earlier

Comment: once your issue is resolved then please accept above answer

Comment: I have tried, but just can't get through.Really Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Update the last line as below.

```
element2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("RveJvd.snByac")[0].click()
```

That's because `find_elements_by_class_name` will be converted to css by selenium and `.` will be prepended to the locator provided here. As your value have multiple classes and so you have to replace the white space with `.`

Alternatively you can use the below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='RveJvd snByac']").click()
```

And you can use `find_element_by` rather `find_elements`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.However, for by_class_name("RveJvd.snByac") it showed the same problem list out of index and for by_xpath("//*[@class='RveJvd snByac']") it said NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element.